# Redux state shows null[Object object] even when I have filled the state with data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am working on an app using react and redux but the redux state is showing null[Object object]. I have tried troubleshooting it but I dont know where the problem is coming from.

userSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const userSlice = createSlice({
name: 'user', 
  initialState: {
  user: null,
},
reducers: {
login: (state, action) => {
  state.user += action.payload;
},

logout: (state) => {
  state.user = null;
}
},
});

export const { logout, login } = userSlice.actions;

export const selectUser = (state) => state.user.user;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

store.js

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import userReducer from '../features/userSlice';
import appReducer from '../features/appSlice';

export default configureStore({
 reducer: {
 user: userReducer,
 app: appReducer
},
});
```

App.js

```
useEffect(() => {
auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
  console.log(authUser.email);
  if (authUser) {
    dispatch(
      login({
        uid: authUser.uid,
        photo: authUser.photoURL,
        email: authUser.email,
        displayName: authUser.displayName
      })
    )
  } else {
    dispatch(
      logout()
    )
  }
})
}, [dispatch]);
```

[image]
How do I go about it?

Comment: What and where is displaying "null[Object object]"? If I had to guess I think the nesting of all your reducers in a `reducer` key in `combineReducers` may be causing an issue, I think your selector should be `(state) => state.reducer.user.user`.

Comment: @DrewReese My state is what is showing the error "null[Object object]"

Comment: @DrewReese it did not work I am getting "state.reducer" not defined

Comment: What and where is displaying "null[Object object]"? You still haven't shown what/where the error is being thrown. [Minimal, Complete, reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @DrewReese I have updated my question. The error is thrown at the user state after login.

Comment: That isn't an error, you concatenated an object to your initial `null` state. Try something like `null + { foo: 'bar' }` in your console and check the result. What should the result state be for the `user` property after a successful authentication?

Comment: @DrewReese The result after authentication is that it should dispatch login function  and fill in the state with the new values from firebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

It seems the issue is that you incorrectly update your `user` state upon successful authentication. You are doing some sort of concatenation in your `login` reducer.

```
login: (state, action) => {
  state.user += action.payload;
}
```

The `state.user` initial value is `null` and you add an object to it.

```js
const state = {
  user: null,
};

const action = {
  payload: {
    uid: 'authUser.uid',
    photo: 'authUser.photoURL',
    email: 'authUser.email',
    displayName: 'authUser.displayName',
  },
};

state.user += action.payload;

console.log(state.user);
```

## Solution

If your goal is for "The result after authentication is that it should dispatch login function and fill in the state with the new values from firebase" then I think you want to replace the current `state.user` value in the reducer.

```
login: (state, action) => {
  state.user = action.payload;
}
```

```js
const state = {
  user: null,
};

const action = {
  payload: {
    uid: 'authUser.uid',
    photo: 'authUser.photoURL',
    email: 'authUser.email',
    displayName: 'authUser.displayName',
  },
};

state.user = action.payload;

console.log(state.user);
```